# PowerShell exception at Receive-File dialog

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have a PowerShell code like this

```
Import-Function Validate-PowerShell

Test-PowerShell

Try
{
   $ctx = get-item .

   Import-Function Import-RedirectMappings
   $file = Receive-File (get-item "master:\media library\Files") -Title "Upload.." -Description "Upload file" -Overwrite    
       ... other code
}
Catch
{
   $ErrorRecord=$Error[0]
   Write-Log -Log Error $ErrorRecord
   Show-Alert "Something went wrong. See SPE logs for more details."
   Close-Window
}
```

in case `Receive-File` dialog files is not selected and press ok, user see exception:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]   Sitecore.UIUtil.GetBrowserClassString() +393
>   Sitecore.Shell.Controls.Standard.FormPageXmlControl.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +672   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +153
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +250
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +250
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +250
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4081

how it is possible to fix it ?

Comment: I'm not sure much can be done to correct this behavior and still show the Alert window that no files were selected. It's similar to this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/getbrowserclassstring-throws-error-when-installing-a-package-in-sxp8-1u3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue that has been around for some time now. I've [reported this issue](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1094) with the SPE Team.

There is now a fix in place due to be released with 5.1 which changes the alert to a validation message on the existing dialog.

[image: SPE Validation Message]